# Thread - Como Chamar um form dentro de uma Thread iTask?

Tags: delphi, thread

No Delphi 10.2, tenho um Form A que possui uma TTask "Tarefa-A" que dispara uma StoredProcedure no banco Oracle com Firedac. A StoredProcedure atualiza uma tabela de resultados que será usada por um form B o qual tem um gráfico.  Gostaria de chamar o Form B dentro de uma TTask "Tarefa-B", que chama o Forms B com o gráfico e poder voltar ao Form A, enquanto o gráfico fica atualizando no outro forms B !  Usei o seguinte comando para abrir o Form B dentro de uma TTask , MAS CONGELOU A APLICAÇÃO !   Agradeço a ajuda pessoal !

```
procedure TFormA.SpeedButtonChamaGrafico(Sender: TObject);
var
   Tarefaproc, Tarefagrafico : iTask;
begin

// Chamada da StoredProcedure dentro da TTask ==>  funciona corretamente !!

Tarefaproc := TTask.Create( procedure ()
                            begin
                                 with FDStoredProc1 do
                                 begin
                                      Prepare;
                                      Params[0].Value := StrToInt(EditCenario.Text);
                                      Execproc;
                                  end;
                             end);
          Tarefaproc.Start;


// Logo em seguida, chamada do FormB dentro de outra TTASK ==> DÁ ERRO, congela a aplicação !!

Tarefagrafico := TTask.Create( procedure ()
                               begin
                                   try
                                      Application.CreateForm(TformB,FormB);
                                      FormB.ShowModal;
                                   finally
                                      Freeandnil(formB);
                                   end;
                               end);
Tarefagrafico.Start;
```

Comment: Acredito que o congelamento se da pelo `ShowModal`, observe que a tarefa não poderá se encerrar automaticamente, no caso ficaria parada no `ShowModal` desvinculada da Aplicação principal. Teste o `Show` e nos diga o resultado.

Comment: @Junior, farei esta modificação junto com a proposta pelo Kelver , logo abaixo.  Obrigado.

Comment: @Junior, testei o show . Quando uso FormB.show o forms aparece e echa na tela , num piscar de olhos !  Como o FormA é a aplicação principal, aberta com showmodal , a partir dela chamo o FormB com outro showmodal passando assim a ser o foco e não permitindo retornar ao FormA.  Há alguma outra forma de permitir comutar o foco entre dois Forms abertos ?  Agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: O controle é feito apenas pelo `Modal` o problema é que a `Thread` esta desvinculando o "B" da aplicação principal.

Comment: @Junior, achei o erro! Era óbvio , mas minha falta de experiência não  permitiu enxergar de imediato que  a chamada do FormB.Show estava dentro de um Try.. Finally , como  o último comando finally era Freeandnil(formB), isso obviamente fechava e encerrava o form logo após o Show.  Tirei isso e funcionou !  Muito obrigado pelo seu suporte e dicas !

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada é importante ressaltar que TUDO que é feito na UI de aplicações VCL acontece na Main Thread (thread principal), ou seja, não adianta chamar um Form em uma thread, pois isso será processado pela main thread. Nestes casos deve-se, inclusive, usar um método de sincronização para que apenas a thread principal trabalhe naquele instante de tempo, exemplo:

```
//considerando que este código está dentro de uma thread
...
TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin
  MeuForm.Show;
end);
```

Dito isso, você pode chamar seu form B fora de uma thread e, dentro dele, fazer consultas à tabela que a "thread A está alimentando", sem problemas.

É importante ressaltar também que objetos de banco de dados (Queries, SPs, etc) usados dentro de uma thread PRECISAM de um objeto de conexão próprio, de uso exclusivo daquele thread. Em outras palavras, cada thread PRECISA ter sua conexão com o BD.

Com relação a permitir que FormA seja acessado enquanto FormB está visível, como já comentou o @júnior-moreira, só é possível se usar o Show, sem Modal.

Abraços!

Comment: entendi o conceito !  Vou aplicá-lo e ver o resultado.  Sobre a questão da conexão de banco de dados de uso exclusivo da Thread, de fato aconteceu algo estranho, pois eu uso um datamodule e tive erro de acesso ao banco de dados. Resolvi colocando uma conexão e um TstoredProc dentro do próprio formulário. É esta a forma correta de fazer a conexão exclusiva da thread ? Pode me indicar alguma documentação ? Muito obrigado !